# How to get analytics stats for mod_rewrite redirects?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, google-analytics, webserver

I have a website with about 200 apache mod_rewrite rules in httpd.conf, running on apache webserver in redhat.

Here's an example of one of the rules, most of them are short URLs that redirect to really long URLs:

```
 RewriteRule ^grad2014/?$ /registration-and-records/graduation/live/index.html [R=301,L]
```

I've been asked to get some web analytics for these redirects.

"How many people used the URL mysite.com/grad2014?" - Well, I don't really know, because /grad2014 doesn't exist on the webserver, and google analytics are set up on the index.html page.

I don't seem to see any of the shortcuts in the access.log.  Is there another way to see which URLs redirects are the most popular ?  Is there a way to start logging this ?

Answer (score 5):

One way you could do it:

Add the rewrite match as a query param on the target url:

```
RewriteRule ^grad2014/?$ /registration-and-records/graduation/live/index.html?rr=$0 [R=301,L]
```

Then in your GA code, capture that URL param and put it in a custom variable. I don't know if you know anything about [custom variables](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables), but here is an example of one way to set it:

```
// example function get query param. use your own if you already have one
function getParam(n){var n=n||'';var x=new RegExp("[\\?&]"+n.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]")+"=([^&#]*)");var r=x.exec(window.location.href);return(r==null)?'':r[1]}

var rr = getParam('rr');
if (rr) {
  _gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 1, "Mod Rewrite Redirect URL", rr, 3]);
}
// your on-page trigger
_gaq.push(["_trackPageview"]);
```

**NOTE:** by default GA counts the page name as `location.pathname+location.search` so adding the `rr` param to the url is going to affect your pages report. The easiest way to fix this is to create a filter within GA to strip it from incoming page name (request URI), but if you need to, you can write some code to get `location.pathname+location.search` minus `rr` query param and populate that value as the 2nd element in your `_trackPageview`.

```
_gaq.push(["_trackPageview","custom page name here"]);
```

Comment: Is it able to make it work with external website? Can I do something like: RewriteRule ^grad2014/?$ http://middle-man-track-traffic.com?rr=$0, following by RewriteRule http://middle-man-track-traffic.com http://external.com [L]

Answer (score 3):

The access.log should give you what you want e.g.

```
cd /var/log/apache2 || cd /var/log/httpd

# Get a list of the 301 redirects issued.
grep 301 access?log


# Count the 301 redirects issued.
grep 301 access?log | wc -l

# Count a specific redirect
grep 301 access?log | grep grad2014 | wc -l
```

Comment: perhaps OP wasn't doing it right, but he did mention he was unable to find the urls in the access log.. but even if so, if it were me (and this is just IMO), I'd rather set something up that would allow for the people wanting the numbers to a) see the numbers for themselves and not keep asking me for numbers, and b) bonus that the numbers would be tied into other visitor activities on the site, not just a simple hit counter.

Comment: The access logs will contain the entries, and they're generally more convenient than embedding additional code into a page/template for a one off report. You also won't have the Change/Test/Release management and likely week or two lead time associated with a page change. If it's pretty pictures your after there are numerous log analysers around: analog, awstats, webalizer, sawmill, cacti......